# NO_DATA_FOUND, SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var and var IS NULL clarification on triggers

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was reading that a `SELECT` that doesn't retrieve any data will generate `NO_DATA_FOUND`.

But for my experience this isn't true because I did a

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO mylocalvar FROM tbl;
```

on an empty table and it didn't launch NO_DATA_FOUND exception.

Instead I found out that `mylocalvar` was `NULL`.
I excepted it to be `= 0` but it was `NULL`.

So basically if I need to check if that `count(*)` is `= 0` I have to:

```
IF mylocalvar IS NULL THEN
  --do stuff
```

Is this right? Also why in this case NO_DATA_FOUND doesn't apply?
Can I assign mylocalvar a 0 value as default? Maybe in the declare:

```
DECLARE
   mylocalvar NUMBER := 0;
```

So I can just do `IF mylocalvar = 0 THEN` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why your query would return `NULL`. It should return exactly one row, that's why the exception is not thrown.

Since your table has no rows, `COUNT(*)` is `0`. This is stored in `mylocalvar`.

---

Try the following code, it outputs
`0`

```
DECLARE
  mylocalvar  PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO mylocalvar
    FROM dual
   WHERE 1 = 2;
  dbms_output.put_line(mylocalvar);
END;
```

Comment: @yes123: Now that's something different. This should explain it: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=4399231#4399231